# Skype wrapper installation error

Tags: 13.10, software-installation, skype, dependencies

When I try to install skype-wrapper in Ubuntu 13.10 I get the next errors (I have tried install python-skype and skype4py) :

```
sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper
```

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

skype-wrapper : Depends: python-skype (>= 1.0.31) but it is not going to be installed

```
             Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf but it is not going to be installed

             Depends: python-indicate but it is not going to be installed

             Depends: python-support (>= 0.90.0) but it is not going to be installed

             Depends: python-wnck but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: What happens when you try 'apt-get -f install' ?

Comment: It seems that you got a `The following packages have unmet dependencies:` error message when trying to install the skype-wrapper package for Ubuntu 13.10 from ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa.